# Integral of $L^2$ function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lp-spaces

For $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, denote $$s_N(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-N}^N\hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}dt.$$

I'd like to prove that the integral converges, and that $s_N$ is continuous.

Since $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we know that also $\hat{f}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. So $$\left|\int_{-N}^N\hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}dt\right|\leq\int_{-N}^N|\hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}|dt=\int_{-N}^N|\hat{f}(t)|dt\leq\left(\int_{-N}^N|\hat{f}(t)|^2dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{-N}^N1dt\right)^{1/2}$$ The right-most term is finite because $\hat{f}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, why is $s_N$ continuous? It looks like an application of the dominated convergence theorem, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just differentiate under the integral sign (your limits of integration are finite, so life is good), and you will see that $s_N$ is differentiable, hence continuous.

Comment: "Just differentiate under the integral sign (your limits of integration are finite, so life is good)" << Could you please explain this part in more detail? I'm not so familiar with the procedure. Thanks.

Comment: Differentiate the function under the integral sign with respect to $x.$ Check out this question, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440647/differentiation-under-the-integral-sign

Comment: Okay, so if I can put the differentiation under the integral sign, I'll get $\dfrac{ds_N(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-N}^Nit\hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}dt$. And so I only need to show that this last term is finite, right?

Comment: @MikaH. Yes, exactly, but since your limits are finite, you do it exactly the same way as you proved your function exists...